# Notify data set changed not working in 4.1.2 after orientation changes

Tags: android

In my app I have, one listview with custom adapter. in that one one check box is there. if i click on that one 2 options will come. If I click on any one option, I am clearing the check box Checked position to unchecked and notifydatasetchanged. every thing working fine in 4.1.2 and 4.1.1. If I click on listview and change orientation and click on any one option that check state is same in 4.1.2. but in 4.1.1 that check box state unchecked. i am thinking problem with notifydatasetchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
yourlist.invalidateviews();
```

Comment: I used listview.invalidateview(); Still problem is coming some times

Comment: Facing the same issue in jelly bean OS, anybody have a solution?